# how to replace string in dataframe on specific column and row?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

```
pandas.DataFrame
({"POC":['K3525','P022','P0025'],
"AREA":['3','',''],
"COUNTRIES":['KR,US,MO','MY,IN,ZW,KR,US','VN,UK,ZW']})
```

| POC | AREA | COUNTRIES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| K3525 | 3 | KR,US,MO |
| PO22 |  | MY,IN,ZW,KR,US |
| P0025 |  | VN,UK,ZW |

in this DataFrame, i want replace ',ZW' or 'ZW,' to ' '(i mean delete it) at one data(row index is 'P0025', column is 'COUNTRIES')

i searched about it, but i can't find any method to set column and row.
i found something like

```
df.replace({'COUNTRIES': {',ZW':'', 'ZW,':''}})
```

but this method remove all 'ZW' in COUNTRIES column.

desired result is

| POC | AREA | COUNTRIES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| K3525 | 3 | KR,US,MO |
| PO22 |  | MY,IN,ZW,KR,US |
| P0025 |  | VN,UK |

not desired result is

| POC | AREA | COUNTRIES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| K3525 | 3 | KR,US,MO |
| PO22 |  | MY,IN,KR,US |
| P0025 |  | VN,UK |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
m = df['POC'].eq('P0025')

df[m] = df[m].replace({'COUNTRIES': {',ZW':'', 'ZW,':''}})
```

Or:

```
 df.loc[m, 'COUNTRIES'] = df.loc[m, 'COUNTRIES'].replace({',ZW':'', 'ZW,':''})
```

Comment: i tried but ',ZW' is not removed :( ...... i don't know why it doesn't work.